# upload image with multer and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs, multer

I'm trying to upload a photo with multer and express and everything is ok. But when I want to create a directory dynamically using fs library, I need access to `req.body.name` in destination in the `multer.diskStorage()` function.

Is this possible?

This is my code :

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/products');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpg') {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ".jpg");
        }
        else if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' ) {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ".jpeg");
        }
        else if (file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ".png");
        }
        else if(file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype !== 'image/png' ){
            return false;
        }
    }
});

var Create_products = multer({ storage : storage , limits: {files:1 }}).single('PRODUCT_PHOTO');
```

Is it wrong or not?

Comment: you want to have a dynamic possibility based on inputs where your data must be stored?

Comment: yeap i want create dynamically folders...and each folder have some information like img or video or ....

Answer (score 0):

I personally have made use of ngFileupload module at the frontend (Angular js) from there I send data along with files and I am accessing that by `req.body.fieldname`, I am usking mkdirp module at place of fs, you can obviously choose whatever you want.

I have give demo sample to implement the whole thing.

Let me know if you need any clarification. Best of luck.

Route

```
app.post('/whatever', funcname.single('file'), thisiscalledafterupload, route.func);
```

Upload Function

```
var funcdata = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {

        var newfoldername = req.body.foldername; //here the folder name is passed along with the files - I have used angular (ngfileupload)
        mkdirp(__dirname + 'somethingroot/folder/' + newfoldername, function (err) {
            console.log(__dirname);
            if (err) console.error(err)
            cb(null, __dirname + 'somethingroot/folder/' + newfoldername);
        });
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {

        var f = Date.now() + '_';
        cb(null, f + file.originalname)
            //file saved now the thisiscalledafterupload will be called
    }
})
var funcname = multer({
    storage: funcdata
});
```